# Database structure for thousands of posts

Tags: database, post-meta, scale

I need to make a large custom customer database and was how to structure it in WP. It will run without woocommerce or anything. The client will not have access to the dashboard. There will be approximately 10,000 customers.

The data is rather simple. Each customer needs the following:

- Name
- Email
- Customer ID (not post ID)

Also each customer need a transaction history including:

- Name of the product
- Date
- Amount purchased

My inital idea was to make a CPT (customer) and store all data as metadata for the post. I'm a bit in doubt how to effectively store the transaction history. It could be stored as an array in metadata containing each transaction as a subarray.

My general worries are

1. That the postmeta for transactions will get too long if a customer has 10+ purchases
2. That the general database handling for retrieving post meta will be extremely slow.

So I'm seeking advice on how to structure a setup like this so it will be fast and also scaleable.

Comment: Look at a plugin called Participant Database. It is for storing people and has options for adding fields. Basically, it does not make sense to use the post table for people. The user table, maybe, but more likely your own table, which is what a lot of plugins do for you.

Comment: So I guess you are just trying to make a WordPress be a database interface for your customer data? If this is strictly for admin use when you dont have to worry about performance too much, using postmeta seems entirely fine. WordPress has internal caching mechanisms for taxonomy and postmeta I believe.